# How can I control legend items through a custom button in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking for a way of controlling legend items through my custom button.
The button will be placed out of the canvas area.
How can I get a list of legend items, and toggle them through checkboxes?
By doing that, I can give users more spaces to see graphs.

Thanks,

Sung Am YANG

Comment: could you please share the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the legend item names using

```
chart.series[0].name
chart.series[1].name
```

To toggle axes on and off, use

chart.series[0].show()
   chart.series[0].hide()

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/BasRN/ shows hiding and showing the first series with buttons, including setting the button text to the series name.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I'm considering to replace the normal legend box to a checkbox list having items.